# Vue js auth check globally

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have this in my main blade

```
<script>
    window.App = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        'user' => Auth::user(),
        'signedIn' => Auth::check()
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

But when I use `window.App.signedIn` in my vue file it gives me undefined output

Comment: May be you need to parse json on the client ? I think you are trying to get a property **signedIn** from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the App setup object appears before your script. Otherwise, you need to wrap your code that relies on window.App to run after the page loads.

Option 1:

```
<script>window.App = @json([...])</script>

...

<script>/* The code relying on window.App */</script>
```

Option 2:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        /* The code relying on window.App */
    })
</script>

...

<script>window.App = @json([...])</script>
```